# Cannot extra Image Url from Element Extensions

Tags: c#, xml, rss

I'm trying to read from what Goodreads offers as an RSS feed and I'm struggling. It seems to work alright for the basic stuff like title and such, but I can't seem to pull the image URL out of the element `book_image_url`.

EDIT: feed was inaccessible without an account, so here's the XML for an item in the feed:

```
<item>
    <guid><![CDATA[https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/5692294949?utm_medium=api&utm_source=rss]]></guid>
    <pubDate><![CDATA[Sun, 23 Jul 2023 11:28:33 -0700]]></pubDate>
    <title>Supergirl: Woman of Tomorrow</title>
    <link><![CDATA[https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/5692294949?utm_medium=api&utm_source=rss]]></link>
    <book_id>59854151</book_id>
    <book_image_url><![CDATA[https://i.gr-assets.com/images/S/compressed.photo.goodreads.com/books/1639946077l/59854151._SY75_.jpg]]></book_image_url>
    <book_small_image_url><![CDATA[https://i.gr-assets.com/images/S/compressed.photo.goodreads.com/books/1639946077l/59854151._SY75_.jpg]]></book_small_image_url>
    <book_medium_image_url><![CDATA[https://i.gr-assets.com/images/S/compressed.photo.goodreads.com/books/1639946077l/59854151._SX98_.jpg]]></book_medium_image_url>
    <book_large_image_url><![CDATA[https://i.gr-assets.com/images/S/compressed.photo.goodreads.com/books/1639946077l/59854151.jpg]]></book_large_image_url>
    <book_description><![CDATA[<b>It’s Supergirl like you’ve never seen her before, in a character-defining sci-fi/fantasy masterpiece from Mister Miracle writer Tom King and Wonder Woman artist Bilquis Evely!</b><br /><br />Kara Zor-El has seen some epic adventures over the years, but she now finds her life without meaning or purpose. Here she is, a young woman who saw her planet destroyed and was sent to Earth to protect a baby cousin who ended up not needing her. What was it all for? Wherever she goes, people only see her through the lens of Superman’s fame.<br /><br />Just when Supergirl thinks she’s had enough, everything changes. An alien girl seeks her out for a vicious mission. Her world has been destroyed, and the bad guys responsible are still out there. She wants revenge, and if Supergirl doesn’t help her, she’ll do it herself, whatever the cost. Now a Kryptonian, a dog, and an angry, heartbroken child head out into space on a journey that will shake them to their very core. <br /> <br />This volume collects <i>Supergirl: Woman of Tomorrow #1-8.</i>]]></book_description>
    <book id="59854151">
      <num_pages>224</num_pages>
    </book>
    <author_name>Tom King</author_name>
    <isbn>1779515685</isbn>
    <user_name>Robert</user_name>
    <user_rating>5</user_rating>
    <user_read_at><![CDATA[Sun, 21 May 2023 00:00:00 -0700]]></user_read_at>
    <user_date_added><![CDATA[Sun, 23 Jul 2023 11:28:33 -0700]]></user_date_added>
    <user_date_created><![CDATA[Fri, 14 Jul 2023 10:10:46 -0700]]></user_date_created>
    <user_shelves></user_shelves>
    <user_review></user_review>
    <average_rating>4.30</average_rating>
    <book_published>2022</book_published>
    <description>
      <![CDATA[
      <a href="https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/59854151-supergirl?utm_medium=api&amp;utm_source=rss"><img alt="Supergirl: Woman of Tomorrow" src="https://i.gr-assets.com/images/S/compressed.photo.goodreads.com/books/1639946077l/59854151._SY75_.jpg" /></a><br/>
                                      author: Tom King<br/>
                                      name: Robert<br/>
                                      average rating: 4.30<br/>
                                      book published: 2022<br/>
                                      rating: 5<br/>
                                      read at: 2023/05/21<br/>
                                      date added: 2023/07/23<br/>
                                      shelves: <br/>
                                      review: <br/><br/>
                                      ]]>
    </description>
  </item>
```

Here's my code:

```
    var reader = XmlReader.Create(_goodreadsSettings.GoodreadsProfileUrl);
    var feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(reader);
    var feedItems = limit > 0 ? feed.Items.Take(limit) : feed.Items;
    var items = feedItems.Select(i =>
    {
        //NOTE: I'm doing this in this way because there is no namespace on these elements
        var syndicationElementExtensions = i.ElementExtensions
            .Where(e => e.OuterName == "book_image_url" && e.OuterNamespace == "").ToList(); //cannot preview the value of this variable in Visual Studio at all, so I can't tell what's happening
        var imageUrl = syndicationElementExtensions
            .Select(e => e.GetObject<XmlElement>().SelectSingleNode("book_image_url")?.InnerText)
            .FirstOrDefault();

        var link = i.Links.FirstOrDefault()?.Uri.AbsoluteUri;

        return new GoodreadsItem
        {
            Title = i.Title.Text,
            Summary = i.Summary.Text,
            Url = link,
            ImageUrl = imageUrl,

        };
    });
    return items;
```

Now, even though Visual Studio won't let me view the value of syndicationElementExtensions when I hover or use a Watch, I was able to view it by running the Where code in the Immediate Window, and it gave me this:

```
OuterName: "book_image_url"
OuterNamespace: ""
_buffer: {System.ServiceModel.XmlBuffer}
_bufferElementIndex: 1
_extensionData: null
_extensionDataWriter: null
_outerName: "book_image_url"
_outerNamespace: ""
```

This doesn't tell me much more, but clearly there's a value in there at one point. But then I can't seem to extra it using the `GetObject<XmlElement>` code on the next line. Is there something weird about the feed, do I need to do it another way?

Comment: It is better to use LINQ to XML

Comment: The link you provided is NOT an XML file.  To download an xml file the URI is different (ends with xml) and you need an account.  I tried using my browser to get the xml file and failed because I did not have an account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ended up being that the element I needed was a Child element, so I was able to get it using the following code:

```
var imageUrl = i.ElementExtensions
    .Where(e => e.OuterName == "book_large_image_url" && e.OuterNamespace == "").ToList()
    .Select(e => e.GetObject<XmlElement>()?.FirstChild?.InnerText)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```